# Как сделать шифрование простой заменой на PHP?

Tags: php, шифрование

В образовательных целях делаю шифрование простой заменой на php.

```
const LETTERS = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
const CODEMAP = "ЯВМЭУЫШТЬЖОЕЁНХСИЧЗЦПЩАЪКРЮЙЛБФГД";

function encrypt($string)
{
    return str_replace(
        mb_str_split(LETTERS),
        mb_str_split(CODEMAP),
        $string
    );
}

function decrypt($string)
{
    return str_replace(
        mb_str_split(CODEMAP),
        mb_str_split(LETTERS),
        $string,
    );
}
```

Но к сожалению не получается сделать декодирование строки:

```
$str = encrypt("ПРИВЕТ КАК ДЕЛА?");
echo $str; // "ИКЖАЛЙ ЕДЕ ПЛЁД?"
echo decrypt($str); // "УЧУХЫЪ ЧЯЧ УЫЫЯ?"
```

**UPD: Использую кодировку utf-8, версия PHP 8.0**

Comment: Укажите кодировку или используйте strtr()

Comment: strtr не может в utf-8

Comment: Это вы с чего решили? Вот код плагина с 200,000+ установок: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/cyr2lat/trunk/src/php/class-main.php#L367

Comment: с того что пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код.

```
const LETTERS = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
const CODEMAP = "ЯВМЭУЫШТЬЖОЕЁНХСИЧЗЦПЩАЪКРЮЙЛБФГД";

$str = strtr( 'ПРИВЕТ КАК ДЕЛА?', LETTERS, CODEMAP );
echo $str . "\n";
echo strtr( $str, CODEMAP, LETTERS ) . "\n";

echo mb_internal_encoding() . "\n";
```

Вот результат выполнения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Вот код, который работает для любых символов.

```
const LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя';
const CODEMAP = 'mтЬJЁrФYQорЛДфмhсSТУXkWзqFVKхЖpХРНlЮyедiКnDбRСЩйЗeCgBxЕЙdЯЪПTOjкsжыvUaЧbEВfАGиБcчэNвAъёwщHацuгtЦЭОPШуZМЫzoлянLшИIMГюьп';

$letters_arr = mb_str_split( LETTERS );
$codemap_arr = mb_str_split( CODEMAP );

$str = strtr( 'ПРИВЕТ КАК ДЕЛА?', array_combine( $letters_arr, $codemap_arr ) );
echo $str . "\n";
echo strtr( $str, array_combine( $codemap_arr, $letters_arr ) ) . "\n";
```

Результат:

```
DбЮхХС еVе pХдV?
ПРИВЕТ КАК ДЕЛА?

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В данном примере все действительно работает. Но если взять значения замен посложней, то кодировка ломается. Попробуйте сделать - const LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
const CODEMAP = "mтЬJЁrФYQорЛДфмhсSТУXkWзqFVKхЖpХРНlЮyедiКnDбRСЩйЗeCgBxЕЙdЯЪПTOjкsжыvUaЧbEВfАGиБcчэNвAъёwщHацuгtЦЭОPШуZМЫzoлянLшИIMГюьп";

Comment: Дал update - рабочий код для любых символов.